# mysql math operations - where clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause

hello i would like to create average length time for each day.

i have following sql :

```
select left(entry_date,10) as datum
,round(avg(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,entry_date,modify_date)),0) as dlzka
from vicidial_list
where entry_date is not NULL and left(entry_date,7)="2016-07" and list_id="490" and avg(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,entry_date,modify_date))<1000
group by left(entry_date,10) asc;
```

can anybody please give me a hint?

Thanks

Comment: You can't use an aggregate function in the `WHERE` clause. Aggregation isn't done until after you select all the rows, the `WHERE` clause is used to select the rows.

Comment: Use `HAVING dlzka < 1000` instead of `and avg(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,entry_date,modify_date))<1000`

Comment: and will it cause that it will make whole avarege between those 2 timestamps that are less than 1000?

Comment: It will calculate the average for each day, and show the days where the average is less than 1000.

Comment: and when i want for each calculation use only differencies that are less then 1000seconds ? average of each row with length less than 1000?

Comment: Then just use `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, entry_date, modify_date) < 1000` in the `WHERE` clause, without `AVG()` around it.